# How to obtain the distance (in Km/Miles and in minutes) by road ?. for example using googlemaps

Tags: geography, external-calls, geodesy, internet

How to obtain the distance between 2 geographical points (knowing the latitute and longitude)

One easy way in the web is 
[https://www.google.es/maps/dir/42.6897189,-8.4912382/42.\
8659508,-8.6709907/@42.7548419,-8.6133146,11.17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0](https://www.google.es/maps/dir/42.6897189,-8.4912382/42.%5C%208659508,-8.6709907/@42.7548419,-8.6133146,11.17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0)

Ok, but... how can you get the results of that in the Mathematica?

for example in a variable distance, and other mins

I try using Import["https://www.google.es/maps/dir/42.6897189,-8.4912382/42.\
8659508,-8.6709907/@42.7548419,-8.6133146,11.17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0"]
but... I can´t reach a good result.

Edited.- I´m interested in distance by road/car.
I trust in googlemaps, that´s the reason because interesting in learn to extract data from calling googlemaps.

Comment: See: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDistance.html

Comment: ...and `GeoPosition[]` is something you'd be interested in, too. Make sure to study the options of `GeoDistance[]` carefully.

Comment: @b3m2a1I do, but the reference in so many/much instruccion have bad examples for learning. This forum is EXCELENT!, but the refenrece is... not so good!

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) page for Google. It will return the answer in the JSON format, which you can easily import into Mathematica.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`TravelDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TravelDistance.html) and related functions to find the distance by road.  Example:

```
TravelDistance[Entity["City", {"Tokyo", "Tokyo", "Japan"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Osaka", "Osaka", "Japan"}]]

(* Quantity[511.606, "Kilometers"] *)
```

```
td = TravelDirections[{Entity["City", {"Tokyo", "Tokyo", "Japan"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Osaka", "Osaka", "Japan"}]}];

GeoGraphics[{Thick, Line[td]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you, and     TravelTime[{GeoPosition[(*A Estrada*){ 42.6897189, -8.4912382}], GeoPosition[(*Brion*){42.8659508, -8.6709907}]}] for time

Answer (score 1):

If we have to extract data from googlemaps，import as "XMLObject" maybe help.

```
Import["https://www.google.es/maps/dir/42.6897189,-8.4912382/%E5%8D%\
A2%E7%93%A6%E5%B0%94%E6%B2%B3+%E6%B3%95%E5%9B%BD/@44.1899542,-11.\
2060396,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x47f440d3c1d1558b:\
0x3093cafcbe32820!2m2!1d4.052545!2d45.9846475", "XMLObject"];

Cases[%, XMLElement["script", {"nonce" -> ___}, Shortest[{b___}]] :> 
   b, Infinity][[1]]
```

We can find the distance and time data that you want,but maybe diffcult to 
extract.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is what I actually asked, but yes... it´s so difficult, so... by now... I decide to use  the Szabolcs solution, almost, till I or anybody can decrypt that data object.

Comment: @MikaIke Google Maps has an API. You can read up on how to use it, get an API key, and experiment. https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I know, but it´s a little complicate for me. I like your solution by now. All works fine a minute ago, but after cloase an open the notebook.

TravelDistance[GeoPosition[{ 42.6897189, -8.4912382}], 
 GeoPosition[{42.8659508, -8.6709907}]]
TravelTime[{GeoPosition[{ 42.6897189, -8.4912382}], 
  GeoPosition[{42.8659508, -8.6709907}]}] gives the error Replace::reps: {$CURLOptions} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

I don´t know how.

Comment: incredible. Now... after close/open mathematica,... all works fine

Comment: @Mika, yes, if you're experiencing anything weird, it is often a good idea to close and reopen just to be sure it isn't something that randomly came up.